# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT gives partially encoded uri

Tags: android, uri

I open the file picker with an ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent and get an uri partially encoded:
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ATest.pdf
If I decode this uri and then give it to an ACTION_VIEW intent, I can't open the document (permission refused).
Why the uri I initially get is partially encoded ?

Comment: Please post complete onActivityResult code where you use ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: `If I decode this uri ` Whatever that would be... you should not do anything with that uri to begin with.

Comment: Further it is not encoded. It is as it is.

Comment: "If I decode this uri" -- do not do that. Treat the `Uri` as an opaque identifier. Do not make any assumptions about its structure. Do not try changing it.